# Is there any way to create a telnet cmd in a browser?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, telnet

Straight forwardly, I'm going to apologize as this is going to be more of a "Gimme" question.

I'm trying to create a way to telnet in a browser without enabling telnet services or installing 3rd party programs to run it.

Ex. Open CMD -> Type "telnet lab.sharontools.com"

I know that you can have something like

```
    <a href="telnet://ipaddress">Connect</a>
```

That works completely fine as long as someone enables the telnet service, and if they didn't know how to they could just simply type

```
    pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

inside of a command prompt and it would install it for them, most likely though, a trainee won't know that.

Instead however, is it possible to lets say, wrap an iframe around a telnet command prompt inside of a web-browser?

```
<iframe href="telnet://lab.sharontools.net" height="20%" width="20%"></iframe>
```

Thanks for your input.
If you've seen this question before, feel free to link me.

Comment: Might be duplicate of [Is there a Telnet library for JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725625/is-there-a-telnet-library-for-javascript)

Comment: You are kind of conflating a few things.  I think you are asking for a browser implemented telnet client, but you also talk about an external telnet command.  You're going to have to find one implemented in java or javascript.

Comment: @rrauenza Yes, I'm talking about an external as an example of how I know how to do it currently, sorry for the confusion. 

Yes, I'm looking for a browser implemented telnet client like this one:
[link]http://www.sharontools.com/online-lab/web-connect/

And how I can modify something like this to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [AnyTerm](http://anyterm.org/1.1/install.html), but you need to thoroughly understand how it works.  You will be "hosting" the shell sessions from your server running the AnyTerm daemon.  That could be your end point, or you could telnet from there.

*This has security implications you need to thoroughly understand.*

Your other option is to provide the putty client, which would be an external client to the browser.

There are more resources here https://askubuntu.com/questions/57730/is-there-a-web-based-terminal-ssh-client, but what you need to determine within each client is which need you to deploy a backend, and which will do native telnet or ssh directly from the browser.

I think with those pointers, that should resource you enough to continue your investigation/research.

Comment: Thank you for your help.