# Communicate over Telnet with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, telnet

Need to make a web-based GUI for a machine that can only be reached with Telnet, is it possible to communicate with it in Javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725625/is-there-a-telnet-library-for-javascript

Comment: You'd probably be better using a server-side script as an intermediary. What do you mean "only telnet" though...telnet just opens a raw TCP socket connection. What protocol do you use to talk to the server once you open the socket? You must be sending commands according to some specific format? There are some basic built-in commands in telnet itself but you can't do much that's useful. What else do you use?

Comment: you can do raw tcp/ip with nodejs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Telnet library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725625/is-there-a-telnet-library-for-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no native IO features at all. It depends on the host environment to provide anything like that.

Node.js, for example, has [several telnet modules](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=telnet) available for it, while web browsers allow JS to make only extremely limited types of network connections (HTTP and Web Sockets).