# SSL encryption over server to server socket.io connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have 2 node.js instances on separate boxes that use socket.io to communicate. Though they sit on the same network behind a firewall, I'd like them to communicate with SSL encryption.

The following works fine:

Server1:

```
require("socket.io").listen(9000);
```

Server2:

```
require("socket.io-client").connect("wss://10.0.0.1:9000");
```

Though I haven't provided any key pairs, so what's going on here? Has a secure channel been established just by specifying wss:? If so, how, without any keys?

Incidentally, this does not work...

```
require("socket.io-client").connect("https://10.0.0.1:9000");
```

(though http: does)

Comment: Your https connection probably doesn't work because your server is not configured for https.

Answer (score -1):

Adding wss won't make the connection use ssl.

On the client side, there is two ways to specify a ssl connection:

- Use https like you did

```
require("socket.io-client").connect("https://10.0.0.1:9000");
```

- use the secure:true option

```
require("socket.io-client").connect("10.0.0.1:9000",{secure: true});
```

Or you can do both to be sure:

```
require("socket.io-client").connect("https://10.0.0.1:9000",{secure: true});
```

Comment: Thanks, but connecting to https: doesn't work. What needs to happen on the server side for the websocket to accept secure connections? I realise you can create an https server and pass that into socket.io's listen method (as below), though I do not want an https server, I want a secure socket (tcp + ssl).

Comment: var httpsServer = https.createServer(keys, handler).listen(443);
    require("socket.io").listen(httpsServer);

Comment: you need a http(s) server to serve websockets (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590447/js-html5-websocket-connect-without-http-call)

Comment: In my case I use a nginx server in front of the websocket server to do ssl termination there.

Comment: Why would we need an HTTP server to serve a websocket connection? They are 2 separate protocols.